# How to redirect every request from user to local host

Tags: windows, networking, lan, redirection

[image: Image shows the how working of system should be]

My question is how to trap traffic going to 202.20.20.20 (The website IP/any dynamic input of website) and redirect to 192.168.1.10

Comment: I don't understand, you want to redirect ALL treaffic to localhost?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111433/iptables-redirect-outside-requests-to-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to set up a SOCKS5 proxy redirecting all traffic to localhost and use the proxy configuration to dynamically forward traffic that should not be redirected to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect everything to localhost, use this command:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 202.20.20.20 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Iptables are used in Linux, I want to configure it in windows.